# In the Hex-Rays decompiler, is it possible to assign macros such as NT_SUCCESS

Tags: hexrays, decompiler

Suppose the decompiler came up with something like this:

```
if (Status >= 0)
{
  // ... some other pseudo code
}
```

Is it possible to prettify this code with the `NT_SUCCESS()` macro, like this:

```
if (NT_SUCCESS(Status))
{
  // ... some other pseudo code
}
```

... which codifies the same condition as shown in the previous pseudo code? I haven't found a way as of yet. It's cosmetic, sure, but it still would be nice to be able to make this sort of adjustment.

Version of IDA 7.7 with matching decompiler.

Comment: I have a similar question, i noticed there are some codes is duplicated in multiple functions. I think it is a inline-function, but how can i collapse it as a inline-function in the Hex-Rays?